# jquery clicking on li to dropdown is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is downdown the list when licking on the li.

However, for some reasons it is not working.

#### jquery code

```
$document.read(function(){


        var mainnav = $('#main-nav'),
            openActive = mainnav.is ('.open-active'),
            navActive = mainnav.find ('> .active');

        mainnav.find ('> .dropdown > a').bind ('click', navClick);

        if (openActive && navActive.is ('.dropdown')) {
            navActive.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').show ();
        }


    function navClick (e) {
        e.preventDefault ();

        var li = $(this).parents ('li');

        if (li.is ('.opened')) {
            closeAll ();
        } else {
            closeAll ();
            li.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').slideDown ();
        }
    }

    function closeAll () {
        $('.sub-nav').slideUp ().parents ('li').removeClass ('opened');
    }


});
```

as you see I already bind the correct action to the `a tag`

#### Please tell me what is wrong in my code not giving me a completely new code, I am not asking for a NEW solution, I am asking about what my mistake is

appreciate your help and time and efforts.

Comment: Please correct document ready in your code...$(document).ready  check this ..http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/ScLe8/1/

Comment: document ready was the problem in your code and now its working very fine

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal you must be kidding man. I can't believe that I am this stupid, It is 2 hours working man and I couldn't solve it. I am stupid stupid stupid, however, chrome should tell me that I did this problem. it didn't :( :(

Comment: Has your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct document ready in your code...$(document).ready 
Just replace this

```
$document.read
```

with

```
$(document).ready
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `$document.read` (first line) a typo, or is this your actual code? If it is, then fix it; it should be `$(document).ready`.

Comment: +1 to your efforts, but there is a guy who answered first so it is first to give him the accepted answer. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code change the `$document.read(function(){})` to `$(document).ready(function(){// place your code here})` or `$(function(){ // place your code here})`

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in `ready()` function declaration, you should be declaring `ready()` instead of `read()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Here is the typo
  var mainnav = $('#main-nav'),
  openActive = mainnav.is ('.open-active'),
  navActive = mainnav.find ('> .active');
  mainnav.find ('> .dropdown > a').bind ('click', navClick);

  if (openActive && navActive.is ('.dropdown')) {
    navActive.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').show ();
  }

  function navClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault ();
    var li = $(this).parents ('li');
    if (li.is ('.opened')) {
      closeAll ();
    } else {
      closeAll ();
      li.addClass ('opened').find ('.sub-nav').slideDown ();
    }
  }

  function closeAll () {
    $('.sub-nav').slideUp ().parents ('li').removeClass ('opened');
  }
});
```

Comment: You forgot the more obvious typo.